# Preview of single page\slide in sharepoint document with Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

In sharepoint with help of Microsoft Graph Api it's possible to generate preview of full file (like docx, pptx) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-preview?view=graph-rest-1.0

But is there is a possibility to get data about how many pages\slides in document and generate preview link only to a single page\slide (not exactly to 1st, but to any, otherwise I could use thumbnails)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc properties of a pptx should contain a Slides property in the Content section. You could retrieve that value via a REST API call which uses the Properties method.

Below is an example of such a request (in a Power Automate cloud flow).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, now it's clear how to get slides number, will it be possible to generate preview link for a concrete slide, using same approach?

Comment: Yeah, you can use the slides property from the outputs in another Send an HTTP request action. `outputs('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')?['body']['Slides']`. I have updated the screenshot in my answer to show that example as well. In that example I calculated the second to last page, just for the fun of it :D